# Implement interface and trait into User model

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

I have installed the following package into my application so that users are able to follow and unfollow other users. 
https://github.com/hypefactors/laravel-follow

In the documentation it states:

> Preparing the Eloquent Models To allow an entity to be followed or to
>   follow other entities, the corresponding models have to implement an
>   interface and make usage of a trait.
>
> Here's how we do it for a User and Company entity, where a user will
>   be able to follow a company and the company will be able to be
>   followed:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Hypefactors\Laravel\Follow\CanFollow;
use Hypefactors\Laravel\Follow\Contracts\CanFollowContract;

class User extends Model implements CanFollowContract
{
    use CanFollow;
}
```

However my user model looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;



class User extends Authenticatable
{
```

I have tried including the files in various ways with no success. I assume its something to do with my user model class looking like this:
**class User extends Authenticatable**
and not this:
**class User extends Model**
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

If i do this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

use Hypefactors\Laravel\Follow\CanFollow;
use Hypefactors\Laravel\Follow\Contracts\CanFollowContract;


class User extends Authenticatable implements CanFollowContract
{
    use Notifiable;
    use Uuids;
    use CanFollow;
```

I get the following error:

> Trait 'Hypefactors\Laravel\Follow\CanFollow' not found

Comment: Does the file `vendor/hypefactors/laravel-follow/src/Traits/CanFollow.php` exist?

Comment: Yes, here is what my vendor directory looks like: https://ibb.co/yRMpK84

Comment: Can you do a `composer dump-autoload` and remove the `.php` files in `bootstrap/cache`?

Comment: So i deleted the packages.php and services.php file in the bootstrap/cache directory then ran composer dump-autoload but I am still getting the same error: Trait 'Hypefactors\Laravel\Follow\CanFollow' not found

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-is-class-user-extends-authenticatable-different-from-class-user-extends-model

Would including the interfaces and traits in Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to change package to this: https://github.com/overtrue/laravel-follow which has worked nicely as expected.

@ceejayoz Thanks for your suggestions